# Why does my script not execute on if.up

Tags: shell-script, network-interface

I want to execute a script that starts `synergy` whenever my laptop wifi cards hooks up to a network (for now any, i'll add a filter later). So I wrote a script `/etc/network/if-up.d/999startsynergy' that looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
########################################################################
# script to start synergy 
# for remote mouse & keyboard control
# from my Desktop PC & work laptop
# script by: Ron Eggler 11/05/2016
#
########################################################################
#
# This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
#
########################################################################
#
# Configuration:
#
host1='DesktopHome'
host2='GEnotebook'
bin='/usr/bin/synergyc'

case $1 in
        up)
        sleep 5
        $bin $host1
        $bin $host2
        ;;
        *) exit 0
esac
exit 0
```

but nothing happens when I disable and re-enable my network card but if I execute `./999startsynergy up` manually, it works just fine! I've also tried with & without the 5 second delay - same thing... any idea what might be going on here?

Comment: Which distribution are you running?

Comment: @zeppelin Kubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 2):

*synergyc* requires an access to the X11 server (display), and should normally be run as a regular user too.

Scripts in */etc/network/if-up.d/* in turn, are run as *root*, and do not have access to your X11 display, which is why it does not work for you.

What you can do, is configure *synergyc* to connect to a proper X11 display (which will be *:0*, usually), by setting a DISPLAY environment variable, or supplying "--display" option to *synergyc*.

You can also use *sudo* to launch it as a proper user (that not strictly necessary, but is probably a good idea anyway).

Here is a small test script, for you to experiment with:

```
#!/bin/sh
[ "$IFACE" = "wlan0" ] || exit 0
export DISPLAY=:0
sudo -u YOUR_USER_NAME xclock &
```

Replace *YOUR_USER_NAME* with your regular account username, and *wlan0* with your wi-fi interface name (in case it is different), and also make sure that you have *xclock* installed (it is normally a part of x11-apps package), then place this to your */etc/network/if-up.d/*, and try switching the network interface on an off.

If everything goes well a *xclock* will pop-up each time your interface goes up, and you can then modify this to launch *synergyc* instead.